# Reachability in dynamic random graphs

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometry, random-graphs, complex-dynamics

There has been some advice on how to ask questions. So I reask my question.I have a problem related to graph theory, random graphs or random geometric graphs in special that really confuses me. Assuming Graph G with node set V={x1,x2,…,xn}, all the nodes are moving in R2 space. There is an edge between xi and xj if and only if the Euclidean distance is less than r(r is a constant). If the distance is larger than r due to the movement, the edge breaks. Edges emerge and break as a result of nodes movement. Assuming the movement is modeled by Brownian motion, I would like to analysis the property of reachability. Given a time threshold T and the speed of node movement , how can I analysis the probability of that one node can find a path to any node during T from time dimension?  The key is the movement of nodes and edges break and emerge with time passing. How to compute the orobability of reachiabiliy?Thanks very much!

Comment: Does each particle move as an _independent_ Brownian motion? Are you looking for the probability at a fixed time $t$ you have a connection between $x_1$ and $x_2$? Or the probability that $x_1$ and $x_2$ were ever connected during the interval $[0,T]$? What are the initial conditions of the positions?

Comment: You might find some literature under "dynamic ad-hoc wireless networks," because unit-distance graphs (UDGs) are a prevalent model for such networks. I don't know this literature well enough to point you to something specific...

Comment: Response to Bati: Each particle moves as an independent Brownian motion. I'm looking for the probability of reachability that x1 can reach x2 during a fixed timeslot T. "Reach" means that x1 can find a path to x2 in time dimension as edges emerge and disappear as a result of nodes movement.  At the very first, nodes are randomly distributed  as a Possion.                 
Respond to Joseph O'Rourke: I have read many papers related to dynamic ad-hoc wireless networks, but most of them do simulation instead of theoretical analysis. Thanks all the same!

Comment: Respond to Joseph O'Rourke: I have read many papers related to dynamic ad-hoc wireless networks, but most of them do simulation instead of theoretical analysis. Thanks all the same!

Comment: I think it is best to specialise to particular limits - high and low density, for example.  At high density, reachability is complete except for a few isolated nodes.  At low density, it is probably related to extreme value theory of the Brownian motion.

Comment: It's really complicated to analyze this problem with StochasticProcess only. I'm searching a way or an area related to it.However, when adding time domain to these methods, they become complicated as well. This really caonfuses me!